# Make ligatures in Linux Libertine copyable (and searchable)

Tags: pdftex, ligatures, libertine, copy-paste

I'm currently working on an essay written in LaTeX form. I'm facing problems with ligatures - in my pdf output (rendered using `pdftex`) opened in Adobe Reader I get X's and V's when copy-pasting words including ligatures (ffi, fi, etc.).

I have tried both the `cmap` and the `mmap` package - I have tried the `mmap` package with and without the `noTeX` parameter without success. To speed up rendering time, I'm pre-compiling headers - can this cause problems do you think? I am putting the `\usepackage{mmap}` directly under the `\documentclass` command, however it is in the header that I have pre-compiled - do you suspect this might be of a problem? If so, what would you recommend I do? I would like to, as much as possible, keep my header-hierarchy for the sake of compiling time, but then again, if that's the only way to go then I'm willing to get rid of it.

I am using the Linux Libertine font - might this be of trouble?

Below is my header and the beginning and end of my document:
http://latex.pastebin.com/51MUAfA6

The lettrine command and package is used to create dropped caps. I am on a Windows system, running the latest MiKTeX version. Is there anything else you would need to know in order to help me out?

Comment: Why don't you try other fonts and other PDF viewers (with and without precompiling headers...) and compare the results? I do get the problem with the `libertine` package with Adobe Reader, but the same document copies and pastes correctly with the evince PDF reader. Switching to computer modern makes it work with either reader.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try the following. And next time make an example with less fancy formatting. Concentrate on the problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\input{glyphtounicode}

\pdfglyphtounicode{f_f}{FB00}
\pdfglyphtounicode{f_f_i}{FB03}
\pdfglyphtounicode{f_f_l}{FB04}
\pdfglyphtounicode{f_i}{FB01}

\pdfgentounicode=1
\begin{document}
ff fl ffi
\end{document}
```

`glyphtounicode.tex` should be in your texsystem in `tex/generic/pdftex`. But you can also find it in the texlive source: https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftex/glyphtounicode.tex

Comment: I deemed it necessary to include the fancy formatting simply because I wasn't sure that it wasn't causing the problem. Your solution works but is somewhat hefty - are you sure there isn't a better way of doing this? I did a c&p in evince and that worked better - why doesn't AReader like ligatures?

Comment: The best would be that libertine corrects the glyph names. cmap will not work (it doesn't work with virtual fonts).  http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-pdftex/2009-December/003870.html, http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb29-1/tb91thanh-fonts.pdf

Comment: @Doggie52: It's better that the person asking the question does the work of figuring out which aspects of their document are responsible for their problem, and removing everything superfluous. It makes it much easier for people to answer the question if it has only the minimal packages and formatting necessary to demonstrate the issue. That way you are likely to get more answers and better ones.

Comment: I shall keep this in mind, Lev!

Comment: This does not, however, work if you compile with XeTeX/XeLaTeX, cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110354/pdfglyphtounicode-with-xetex

Comment: This wasn't working for me since I had an empty `glyphtounicode.tex` file (as the one provided by TeX Live triggers a [bug in Ghostscript](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=704681)). The problematic `\input{glyphtounicode}` can be replaced by the following 3 mappings: `\pdfglyphtounicode{f}{0066}` `\pdfglyphtounicode{i}{0069}` `\pdfglyphtounicode{l}{006C}`.