# Insert negative kern before "Y" in Calabi-Yau

Tags: ligatures, kerning

Some pairs of glyphs look more visually appealing when a kern is inserted between the glyphs.  For instance, if the word Calabi–Yau is typeset with a font that does not include kerning information for the pair (–,Y), the space between the end of the en-dash and the stem of the letter Y is too large.  Compare the results of `Calabi--Yau` without or with a kern:

[image: Calabi–Yau with differenti kernings]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Calabi--Yau
Calabi--\kern-.15em Yau
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to automatically insert such a kern, preferably by inserting some code in the preamble, and no extra markup in the document?

Comment: `microtype` has a similar option but I'm even scared to open the manual considering my font related skills..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That probably will break all sort of things …

… for example `\kern--.15em` and `\csname --Y\endcsname`.

Related: [Easily assign undefined ligatures with pdfLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31018/easily-assign-undefined-ligatures-with-pdflatex)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\makeatletter
    \languageshorthands{english}
    \initiate@active@char{-}
    \defineshorthand{--}{%
        \char`-\char`-%
        \@ifnextchar Y{\ifmmode\else\kern-.15em\fi}{}%
    }
\newcommand*{\activateendashYligature}{\bbl@activate{-}}
\newcommand*{\deactivateendashYligature}{\bbl@deactivate{-}}
\makeatother
\activateendashYligature
\begin{document}
Calabi--Yau (\verb|Calabi--Yau|) \par
Calabi--\kern-.15emYau (\verb|Calabi--\kern-.15emYau|) \par
Calabi--{}Yau (\verb|Calabi--{}Yau|)\par
Calabi-Test (\verb|Calabi-Test|)

$ --Y = -{}-Y $ (\verb|$ --Y = -{}-Y $|) \par
--Y $\to$ \deactivateendashYligature --Y \par% turning it off
$ --Y = -{}-Y $ (\verb|$ --Y = -{}-Y $|)\par
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]