# Automatically apply a kern rule for all characters that follow a specific character

Tags: macros, kerning, calligra

I am writing some text using the `\calligra` font and there are some specific instances where I want to manually reduce the kerning between letters.

See the MWE below. I have reduced the kerning between the `N` and `a` letters using `\kern-0.2em`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\calligra 
Insert Name\vspace{.2cm}

Insert N\kern-0.2em ame
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to make this automatic? So I don't have to type `\kern` after every `N`?

I have seen [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87819/insert-negative-kern-before-y-in-calabi-yau) which shows automatic kerning rules can be done using a macro defined in the preamble. But, this case was for one specific combination of characters. I want to make it general for every character that follows an `N`. I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To complement Phelype's answer: if you are using `pdftex`, you may achieve the same result by adding the following lines to the preamble:

```
\usepackage[kerning=true]{microtype}
\DeclareMicrotypeSet*[kerning]{calligra}{encoding = T1, family = calligra}
\SetExtraKerning{encoding = T1, family = calligra}{N = {,-200}}
```

Answer (score 17):

If you can use XeTeX, then you can use `\XeTeXinterchartoks` ([idea by 
ShreevatsaR](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413962/134574)).

First you create a "character class" for the letter N (and for any other you wish):

```
\newXeTeXintercharclass \mycharclassN
\XeTeXcharclass `\N \mycharclassN
```

then you say that XeTeX is supposed to insert `\kern-0.2em` between `N` and any other character (class `0`):

```
\XeTeXinterchartoks \mycharclassN 0 = {\kern-0.2em}
```

then you only need to activate the inter-character tokens with:

```
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1
```

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newXeTeXintercharclass \mycharclassN
\XeTeXcharclass `\N \mycharclassN

\XeTeXinterchartoks \mycharclassN 0 = {\kern-0.2em}

\begin{document}
\calligra

\parskip=0.2cm

Insert Name

Insert N\kern-0.2em ame

\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1

Insert Name

Na Nb Nc Nd Ne Nf Ng

Nh Ni Nj Nk Nl Nm

Nn No Np Nq Nr Ns Nt

Nu Nv Nw Nx Ny Nz

\end{document}
```