# Activating fi and fl ligatures with fontspec for Berling font

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, ligatures

I have a font named Berling containing fi and fl ligatures on glyph 109 and 110. How can I activate these with lualatex? For the moment I am trying:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={BerlIt}, Ligatures={Required}]{Berling}

Fi fi Fl fl \textit{Foo Fii fi}

\end{document}
```

But I get:

```
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Required' (+rlig) not available for font
* 'Berling' with script 'Latin' and language 'Default'.
*************************************************
```

[image]

---

EDIT: I have now also tried (and both with and without Script=Default)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={BerlIt}, Ligatures={Common, TeX}, Script=Default]{Berling}

Fi fi Fl fl \textit{Foo Fii fi}

\end{document}
```

---

Comment: Either the font does not have the features at all, or they are not registered for Latin script, try `Script=Default`, and see if it works.

Comment: Also do not use `inputenc` with lualatex/xelatex. These 2 already assume you use UTF-8 in your source.

Comment: Where did you get the font from?

Comment: The f-ligatures are usually contained in the `Common` ligature group rather than in the `Required` ligature group. You may want to try the option `Ligatures=Common` or, better still, `Ligatures={Common, TeX}` when executing the `\setmainfont` instruction.

Comment: Sadly none of you suggestions made any difference. As for the font having the glyphs I have seen them myself with `Font Book` on my Mac and they are at location 109 and 110. @egreg: I got the font from my University. It has copyright: "Copyright (c) 1991 Adobe Systems Incorporated.  All Rights Reserved.Berling is a trademark of Verbum AB, Stockholm." Gonna update the example with my latest attempt based on your suggestions...

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31218/4427

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to egregs help and this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31218/4427) the I got the following solution which works for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={BerlIt}, FeatureFile=myligatures.fea]{Berling}

Fi fi Fl fl \textit{Foo Fii fi}

\end{document}
```

And the following feature file:

```
languagesystem DFLT dflt ;
languagesystem latn dflt ;
feature liga {
       sub f i by f_i ;
       sub f l by f_l ;
} liga ;
```

[image]

Now I am gonna take a last look at the glyphs in that file and see if there are any other ligatures worth using :)