# How to access the quotation marks in Berling font using lualatex?

Tags: fonts, symbols, luatex, punctuation, fontspec

Here is a small example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,article,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={BerlIt}, FeatureFile=myligatures.fea]{Berling}
\begin{document}
``Lala la''
\end{document}
```

[image]

The myligatures.fea comes from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/activating-fi-and-fl-ligatures-with-fontspec-for-berling-font) and now I would like to use the quotation marks that I know the font have at glyph position 105 and 119 instead. Is there a way I can map these to be used instead?

Worth noticing is that if I copy the unicode symbols from Wikipedia and use them it works, however that would be a pain of search replace and something that I would want LuaLaTeX to do for me...

```
\documentclass[11pt,article,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={BerlIt}, FeatureFile=myligatures.fea]{Berling}
\begin{document}
``Lala la''

“Lala la”
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try adding `Ligatures=TeX` to the options?

Comment: Have now and it worked. Almost too easy...

Comment: I suppose one now should be wondering: “why?”

Comment: The `''` ligature and the similar others are not enabled in OpenType fonts; they're a TeX tradition.

Comment: Sorry for being late in answering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ligatures such as ``` `` ``` for `“` and `''` for `”` are traditional in the TeX world, but they aren't defined in OpenType or TrueType fonts.

The `Ligatures=TeX` option when selecting a font enables them and a few others; with XeLaTeX it loads the `tex-text.map` file (actually its byte encoded equivalent)

```
; TECkit mapping for TeX input conventions <-> Unicode characters

LHSName "TeX-text"
RHSName "UNICODE"

pass(Unicode)

; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
U+002D U+002D                   <>      U+2013  ; -- -> en dash
U+002D U+002D U+002D    <>      U+2014  ; --- -> em dash

U+0027                  <>      U+2019  ; ' -> right single quote
U+0027 U+0027   <>      U+201D  ; '' -> right double quote
U+0022                   >      U+201D  ; " -> right double quote

U+0060                  <>      U+2018  ; ` -> left single quote
U+0060 U+0060   <>      U+201C  ; `` -> left double quote

U+0021 U+0060   <>      U+00A1  ; !` -> inverted exclam
U+003F U+0060   <>      U+00BF  ; ?` -> inverted question

; additions supported in T1 encoding
U+002C U+002C   <>      U+201E  ; ,, -> DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
U+003C U+003C   <>      U+00AB  ; << -> LEFT POINTING GUILLEMET
U+003E U+003E   <>      U+00BB  ; >> -> RIGHT POINTING GUILLEMET
```

so we see that the mapping is

- `--` to en-dash –
- `---` to em-dash —
- `'` to right quote ’
- `''` to double right quote ”
- `` ` `` to left quote ‘
- ``` `` ``` to double left quote “
- `` !` `` to inverted exclamation mark ¡
- `` ?` `` to inverted interrogation mark ¿
- `,,` to German opening quotes „
- `<<` to opening guillemets «
- `>>` to closing guillemets »

With LuaLaTeX some code with the same effect is executed; you can find it by looking for `tlig` in `luaotfload-features.lua`.

Comment: Note that as of version 2.4 of `fontspec`, the `Ligatures=TeX` option is activated by default.