# Monotype Gill Alt One MT and the fi fl ligatures

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, ligatures

I have previously received [help with getting the fi and fl ligatures working with the Berling font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/activating-fi-and-fl-ligatures-with-fontspec-for-berling-font) and now I found myself trying to do the same with the Gill Alt One MT font. The same approach does not seem to be working. With:

```
languagesystem DFLT dflt ;
languagesystem latn dflt ;

feature kern {
pos f h 500;
} kern;

feature liga {
sub f i by f_i;
sub f l by f_l;
} liga;
```

I get:

```
!LuaTeX error (file ./gillsans.TTF): Invalid glyph index (gid 251)
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

It is either the fi or fl but gid 251 is strange. Assuming that gid stands for glyph index I can't understand where 251 is comming from. The glyphs are at position 109 and 110 just as was the case for the Berling font.

I have also tried `Script=Default` in the `setmainfont` call which seems to just have the effect that the feature file is ignored cause the kerning stops working as well. Once again I am at a loss. What else can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First : I am surprised that the file name of Gill Alt One MT could be simply gillsans.ttf…

Second : The names of the f + i and f + l ligatures are *not always* f_i and f_l. In an Monotype font, they may be fi and fl. So, you should try :

```
feature liga {
sub f i by fi;
sub f l by fl;
} liga;
```

Or open the TTF file in fontforge (or run ttf2afm on it) and check the names.

Comment: Yea the font name has changed. I had some trouble with font name at some stage and changed it... Sorry about that.

Comment: yea fi and fl worked. I didn't manage to find the glyphs in FontForge though. There are so many and scrolling through all takes forever... :(