# pdf files show "fi", but searching for or copying them does not work

Tags: fonts, pdftex, ligatures, copy-paste

When I pdflatex text containing "fi", e.g. "infinite", the resulting pdf-file looks correct, e.g. "infinite" is shown in the text. But when I search the pdf file for "infinite", 0 occurrences are found. When I copy "infinite" and paste it, the result is "innite". Searching for "innite" results in 0 occurrences as well.

What causes this behavior? My font not being able to handle ligatures? How can I fix it, such that "fi" is treated the same as any other letter combination?

Comment: What font are you using in which encoding? Try `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: I'm using komascript and the default font (I don't load any package other than komascript that messes with font settings).

Comment: @Martin: thanks, the result looks identical (ie. I don't see any change in the font), but the "fi"-problem is gone. Could you write your comment as answer? Then you could maybe say what the lmodern package is, and why \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} is not sufficient. And I can accept your answer, to help later readers of this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LaTex use ligatures in the text and the PDF-readers treat that as one, unknown character. As far as I remember, I solved the same problem by adding the following two lines in the preamble:

```
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1
```

I found this solution in the [MinionPro manual](http://ctan.uib.no/fonts/minionpro/MinionPro.pdf), page 7.

I use utf8 encoding in my document, *i.e.*

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Also have a look at Ulrike Fischer’s [answer to a similar question regarding Linux Libertine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4398/9632).

`glyphtounicode` was included in the [MiKTeX-](http://www.miktex.org)distribution I use, but if it is not included in yours, you can find it at [Sarovar](http://pdftex.sarovar.org/misc/).

Comment: using only `\input{glyphtounicode}\pdfgentounicode=1` without `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is sufficient to solve the problem. What's the advantage of using glyphtounicode compared to fontenc (and lmodern as mentioned by Martin)?

Comment: I don't know if there is any advantage. My TeX-skills are limited, I am on the level: ‘Find other’s solution to a problem and copy it’.

Comment: @Sveinung, perhaps you should add the link to the `glyphtounicode` file here as well?

Answer (score 5):

This problem can AFAIK be solved by using the *Latin modern* font in T1 encoding:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

I guess it helps the PDF (viewer) to indicate which real letters are represented by the ligatures.

Comment: What's the advantage of using fontenc and lmodern compared to glyphtounicode, as mentioned by Sveinung?