# MinionPro Font-bugs: Copy numbers in pdf with lf option does not work and small caps are not scaled correctly

Tags: pdftex, minionpro

I have experienced the following problem with the MinionPro font with pdflatex and would like to ask if someone has an idea how to solve them:

If I use minionpro package with the "lf" options in order not to use old-style numbers, I cannot copy numbers from the Pdf, all I get is a sequence of "" characters.

Using `\textsc{ss}s` one can clearly see in the output that the size of small caps is slightly bigger compared to the the lowercase character.

I would be very thankful if someone could help me to solve this issues, as I really like Minionpro and do not like to switch the font.

Comment: Please post a Minimum Working Example demonstrating the problem. Also, please explain which version of the fonts you have as there are a lot of different possibilities. (For example, you might have a set of commercial fonts or fonts from one or other version of Adobe Reader or... and these fonts might be one of several versions and...) For example, I just compiled a minimal document which demonstrates neither of the issues you report.

Comment: Add `\input{glyphtounicode}\pdfgentounicode=1` to your preamble after loading `MinionPro`. Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57866/pdf-files-show-fi-but-searching-for-or-copying-them-does-not-work?rq=1

Comment: Jörg, thanks very much, that was the solution. why didn't you write an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Using the following minimal example I cannot observe the first "bug" you're experiencing (at least not on OSX with the Skim PDF reader and v2.3 of the MinionPro package built from the 2.108 version of the Minion Pro OTF fonts):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lf]{MinionPro}
\listfiles

\begin{document}
Number test: 1234 math \(1234\).

Small-caps test: \textsc{ss}s.
\end{document}
```

This means the answer is likely "update your packages", "update your fonts" or "use another PDF reader" — it all depends on what package/font versions you have and what viewer (possibly OS) you're using.

As for the small caps, I'm pretty sure that's by design.