# How can I make the copied-pasted text from an pdflatex output still readable/compilable by pdflatex?

Tags: pdf, unicode, accents, copy-paste, french

### The issue

I compile a `latex` document which contains accents ("é" for instance), then I copy the text from the `pdf` generated by `pdflatex`. Then, I paste this text to my `latex` file.

The resulting file cannot be completed, for some encoding reason.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

#### PS:

My system is OSX.
My TeX distribution is TeXLive.
My PDF previewer is Preview (the default Apple previewer application).

#### PPS:

This problem seems to be related more to Apple's Preview application than anything else.

### Minimal non-working example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

Copy this text "éàoùôêèç" and then paste it here : éàoùôêèç

Then compile again.

\end{document}
```

### The error

> ./Sans-titre.tex:10: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:Ì not
>   set up for  use with LaTeX.
>
> See the inputenc package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.10 ... oÃ¹ÃŽÃªÃšÃ§" and then paste it here : eÌ
>                                               aÌouÌoÌeÌeÌcÌ§
> ```

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me (with and without cmap) on windows and sumatra or adobe reader.

Comment: My system is OSX.
My TeX distribution is TeXLive.
My PDF previewer is Preview (the default Apple previewer application).

Comment: Imho Apple decompose sometimes the glyphs in char+combining accent when you copy & paste. If you don't have this problem when you copy from other pdf's then it is perhaps due to the glyph names. You could then try \pdfglyphtounicode to change them. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4398/2388.

Comment: Yes, it works with Acrobat Reader.

Comment: I am using `\input glyphtounicode \pdfgentounicode=1` when I am using the `IL2` font encoding, or, I am using `xelatex` and `lualatex` engines without the `inputenc` package (I am using `fontspec` instead).

Comment: ... and Apple's Preview application?

Comment: I didn't wrote "if it works in other pdf readers" but "from other pdf's". The question is if apple preview does it always or if there is something special in the pdf's produced by pdflatex (which one could perhaps change).

Comment: Apple does it always IMHO. See http://www.betalogue.com/2004/09/21/pasting-accented-text-from-preview-to-word-how-to-get-the-accented-characters-right/

Comment: It also might be an editor problem, hence a (perhaps naive) question: are you sure your editor saves your .tex file in utf8 format?

Comment: @Bernard Yes I am sure. It is definitively a problem coming from Preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem comes from Apple's `Preview` application up to `OS X 10.9`.
I have not tested on newer versions.

See [there](http://www.betalogue.com/2004/09/21/pasting-accented-text-from-preview-to-word-how-to-get-the-accented-characters-right/).

Comment: You should provide some more detail here. Plus it can be argued that you're not really answering your own question here, since discovering that the problem lies with Preview is not a solution.