# How to type "<<test>>" in ttfamily?

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to produce `<<test>>` text in `\ttfamily`, but it looks like:

```
«test»
```

Which is not what I'm looking for. When I'm trying `$<<$test$>>$` the result is not correct as well because the symbols are not in `\ttfamily`.

This is full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\texttt{<<test>>}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\texttt{<<Hello>>}\end{document}` works fine, you're probably loading some other package which changes the `<<` to `«`.

Comment: @Juan you're right, I altered my question

Comment: You are trying to avoid `\verb|<<test>>|`, aren't you? It will not work well inside macro arguments.

Comment: @Martin sorry, I didn't understand what do you mean. Could you please correct my sample in order to make it working?

Comment: @yegor256: No, your post is fine. You can use `\verb` to write the `<<`/`>>` as verbatim in `\ttfamily`. So `\verb|<<test \macro>>|` will produce `<<test \macro>>`. If you want to avoid the content being typeset verbatim use: `\verb|<<|\texttt{test}\verb|>>|`. As said this doesn't work inside macro arguments etc.

Comment: @Martin I'm lost, sorry :( Could you please give a complete answer? How should **my** document look like in order to produce the result I'm expecting? I don't use `\verb` anywhere in my question.. I don't understand where did you get it...

Comment: @Martin: looks like an answer to me :-)

Comment: yegor, @Joseph: I made an answer out of it, and while writing it I came up with an even better one!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To avoid the combination of two `<` or `>` to `«` and `»` place a `{}` between them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\texttt{<{}<test>{}>}
\end{document}
```

They are combined using the ligatures mechanism. So disabling this one e.g using [`microtype`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) s `\DisableLigatures` would also work, but isn't recommended because it reduces the overall typeset quality.

---

You could also use `\verb` to typeset the `<<`/`>>` verbatim. (There is also the `shortvrb` macro which allows you to make this shorter.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\verb|<<|\texttt{test}\verb|>>|
\end{document}
```

If the content is only text without macros etc. you can use one `\verb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\verb|<<test>>|
\end{document}
```

Using `shortvrb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{shortvrb}
\MakeShortVerb\|
\begin{document}
|<<|\texttt{test}|>>|
|<<test>>|
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

What you are seeing is a ligature: In T1-encoding TeX replaces the << by the doublequote like it replace two dashes -- by an endash. You can avoid it with different methods (the last is drastic):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\texttt{<{}<test>{}>}

\verb+<<test>>+

{\fontencoding{OT1}\texttt{<<test>>}}

\ttfamily \pdfnoligatures\font <<test>> --
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would say that using \verb was undesirable anywhere; it's not just that it
doesn't work in command arguments (in the absence of cprotect.sty, that is).

I would use one of the commands that define a robust command as expanding to
a verbatim string:

```
\usepackage{verbdef}
...
\verbdef\llt|<<|
\verbdef\ggt|>>|
...
\texttt{\llt{}test\ggt}
```

(there are other packages that do this, but verbdef is the one I could
remember)

Comment: +1 for pointing out verbdef, sounds like it could be really useful in plenty situations.

Comment: `\texttt{\llt test\ggt}` will work as well. Macros eat the spaces after them.

Answer (score 2):

another possibility is to go into "raw" tex code:

```
\texttt{\char`\<\char`\<test\char`\>\char`\>}
```

verbose, and works only on one character at a time, but it gets around any
catcode problems that might otherwise be a bother.