# How do I prevent LaTeX from creating en-dash and em-dash?

Tags: ligatures, punctuation

All over the internet, there's this question on how to make LaTeX do the en-dash and em-dash.

I have the opposite problem. I have some text from which I am generating HTML and LaTeX outputs. The original text has nothing to do with LaTeX and therefore `--` and `---` are needed to be written as they are, as opposed to being converted to en and em dashes.

Putting it in `\texttt` should probably solve it, but this could happen in normal text and I'd like to know if there is any other solutions.

P.S. I am writing the LaTeX files with a software, so in fact for example a thing like `\dash{}` instead of every `-` is easier for me, if such a thing exists that is!

Comment: Somewhat related: [How do I disable ligatures? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439651/how-do-i-disable-ligatures)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`--` and `---` are TeX ligatures (like `fl` or `fi`). Disabling ligatures is one of the features of package [microtype](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype). You may deactivate all ligatures of all fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures{}
\begin{document}
---
\end{document}
```

or only the ligatures of the `rm`-family:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures{family=rm*}
\begin{document}
---
\end{document}
```

or only the ligatures `--` and `---` of all fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[-]{}
\begin{document}
---
\end{document}
```

or of one family, e.g. the `tt`-family:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[-]{family=tt*}
\begin{document}
\textrm{---} but \texttt{---}
\end{document}
```

See the manual of package `microtype` for more information about disabling ligatures.

Comment: Nice! This package doesn't come with TexLive, right? I think I'll stick to the accepted answer as I can give the LaTeX files away without instructing people to install additional packages.

Comment: @Shahbaz `microtype` does come with TeX Live.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Have a look at [the package link](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) at my answer. You will find a heading "Getting it" there. Below this heading you will find the information, that there's not only a TeXLive package with `microtype` but a MiKTeX package too. That's a very useful feature of [Jim Hefferon's AZ web views of CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg).

Comment: **Note**: this only works for PDFLaTeX. For XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1841/250119. ■ Note on the terminology used in this answer: "the `tt`-family" does not refer to the font family literally named tt, instead the `tt*` refers to the default typewriter font `\ttdefault` at `\AtBeginDocument`. Quoting `microtype` documentation: "If a value is followed by an asterisk (like `rm*` and `sf*` in the first example),
it does not designate an NFSS code, but will be translated into the document’s
`\〈value〉default`, e.g., `\rmdefault`. "

Answer (score 21):

You could use `{-}{-}` and `{-}{-}{-}` for en-dash and em-dash respectively, or define a command `\dash` that does this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
​\begin{document}
\newcommand{\dash}{{-}}%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
  & Default & \verb!{ }! & \verb!\dash! \\ \hline
  \verb!-! & - & {-} & \dash \\
  \verb!--! & -- & {-}{-} & \dash\dash \\
  \verb!---! & --- & {-}{-}{-} & \dash\dash\dash \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

I assume you'll be able to differentiate between math and text mode, since using `{-}` or `\dash` in math mode would mess up operator spacing.

Comment: Also `-{}-` and `-{}-{}-` works.

Comment: @Jean-ChristopheDubacq: True, but in an automated process, you would probably output `-{}-{}` and `-{}-{}-{}` since `-` would be replaced with `-{}` (or `{}-`).

Comment: **Note**: This does not work in LuaLaTeX: [LuaTeX does not respect brace groups used for disabling ligatures - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349725/luatex-does-not-respect-brace-groups-used-for-disabling-ligatures)

Answer (score 6):

```
\def\normalhyphen{-}
\catcode`-=\active
\protected\def-{\normalhyphen\ifmmode\else\kern0pt \fi}
```

You won't be able to specify negative dimensions by `-`, but you can say

```
\setlength{\mylen}{\normalhyphen 3pt}
```

Comment: What does this code do?

Comment: The code makes `-` into an active character, which behaves like a macro; if it's given in text mode it becomes `-\kern0pt`, which will prohibit a ligature if the following character is again a `-`.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest possibility is use an environment that is designed for verbatim text, such as the `verbatim` environment or the `\verb` command.  I mention it because you said in a comment that you are documenting code and this is a pretty straightforward way to print code.  But it doesn't sound like that is what you want since you've already considered `\texttt`.

Better yet, the `listings` package is designed to produce nicely typeset code with minimal effort.  Personally I've had great results typesetting SQL snippets and even entire Perl scripts.  The brilliant thing about it is that I can import working code from a file and print it well formatted without having to edit the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

For Rmarkdown users: the -{}- doesn't seem to work and curly braces are inserted into the text. However, a workaround is to instead insert ${}$ between any consecutive hyphens. This:

```
-${}$- -${}$-${}$-
```

Outputs as:

```
-- ---
```

Comment: Why the `$` signs,  Math isn't needed here.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It's just an empty math environment that tricks LaTeX into not seeing that there are consecutive dashes. In using LaTeX via Rmarkdown -{}- itself doesn't work. I should probably specify this in the answer

Comment: That makes more sense.  Thanks.  (I'm not an R user.  I still tend to think in plain TeX.)