# unwanted en-dash ligature with lualatex but not with xelatex

Tags: luatex, ligatures, pandoc

I am trying to generate PDF documentation out of Pandoc Markdown README document. Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[english,]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}

\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
    \usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
\fi

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\begin{document}
\texttt{-{}-enable-debugging}
\end{document}
```

When I generate a PDF using `lualatex` (beta-0.76.0-2013070111  (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (rev 4627)) it creates a en-dash instead of typesetting `--`:

[image: unwanted en-dash picture]

The en-dash is unwanted. XeLaTeX does not do that. I want two dashes.

**UPDATE**

In the end, I have created a patch that makes Pandoc use `-\/-` instead of `-{}-` to avoid the ligature.

Comment: Don't use `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}` before declaring the mono font.

Comment: Note also that inserting `{}`, i.e., an "empty TeX group", does *not* work as a ligature-suppressing method under Lua(La)TeX, though it does so under Xe(La)TeX and pdf(La)TeX.

Comment: So how would you break a single ligature in Lua(La)TeX? That is, if you want ligatures generally but need -- or ff without ligaturing in a particular case?

Comment: @cfr - Under LuaLaTeX, I would suggest loading the [selnolig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/selnolig) package. Specify either the `english` or `ngerman` option to load language-specific selective ligature suppression rules, or provide your own homemade ligature suppression rules -- say,  `\nolig{--}{-|-}` -- to suppress certain ligatures on a document-wide basis. To suppress a single instance of a ligature, one could issue the command `\breaklig`, e.g., `\breaklig{pdf|latex}`.

Comment: @Mico Interesting. So there's a solution for English and German but maybe not for other languages. (I don't know if it is an issue in other languages, though. To be honest, I'm not sure of the rules even for English and certainly never use them!)

Comment: @cfr - Fortunately there aren't that many ligature-suppressing rules in English to begin with. :-) (The rule `\nolig{lfful}{lf|ful}` takes care of words such as "shelfful", which is mentioned in the TeXbook...) The situation is quite different with German -- the `selnolig` package features roughly twenty [20!] times as many `\nolig` rules for `ngerman` as it does for `english`.

Comment: I don't find that at all surprising ;).

Comment: Related question: [ligatures - How do I prevent LaTeX from creating en-dash and em-dash? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36692/how-do-i-prevent-latex-from-creating-en-dash-and-em-dash)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in declaring

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
```

before loading the mono font. This will add the common TeX ligatures to the normal set, in particular turns `--` into an en-dash.

---

By the way, you shouldn't load either `xltxtra` or `xunicode`; `xltxtra` has some features, but it's quite improbable you really need them. It used to be recommended when `fontspec` was in its older versions. Now it does the main things `xltxtra` was used for and also loads `xunicode`. Since `mathspec` loads `fontspec` just that package is sufficient.

Also avoid `fontenc` for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Put it in the pdflatex specific part.

Comment: This MWE is derived from Pandoc generated LaTeX document. It adds those bits of its own.

Comment: @wilx Not the best code, to tell you the truth. Besides, thinking that the same document can be processed with the three engines using that preamble is just a dream: you can't emulate `mathspec` with LuaTeX and you can't use a document using specific `mathspec` features with `pdflatex`.

Comment: Pandoc's conversion is best effort. Feel free to improve [Pandoc's LaTeX template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex).