# How to break up ligature in URL

Tags: ligatures, url, jurabib

How can I break up the ligature in fileadmin of this URL? Any idea for a command to be used in `\biburlprefix` and `biburlsuffix`?

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[authorformat={dynamic},titleformat=commasep,titleformat=all,commabeforerest,howcited=compare,annote]{jurabib}

\renewcommand*{\biburlprefix}{}
\renewcommand*{\biburlsuffix}{}
\biburlfont{same}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@WWW{Mitsch,
    title = {Das Kommissionswesen unter Kaiser Friedrich~III.\relax},
    author = {Ralf Mitsch},
    url = {http://www.regesta-imperii.de/fileadmin/user_upload/downloads/Mitsch_2015.pdf},
    urldate = {22.~März~2020},
    shorttitle = {Kommissionswesen},
    howcited = {1}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{Mitsch}

\bibliography{literatur}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}

\end{document}
```

And more general, I hope you agree that breaking up ligatures in URL is a general rule, right?

Comment: Indeed, ligatures in URL stringts look downright weird and wrong to me.

Comment: Crosslink for future readers: Related question that explains usages of DisableLigatures: [ligatures - How do I prevent LaTeX from creating en-dash and em-dash? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36692/how-do-i-prevent-latex-from-creating-en-dash-and-em-dash?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally wouldn't have a problem with ligatures. But if you want to avoid them, you could use OT1-encoding for the url and T1 encoding for the tex and disable the ligatures for OT1:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures{encoding = OT1}
\def\UrlFont{\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
fileadmin

\url{http://www.regesta-imperii.de/fileadmin/user_upload/downloads/Mitsch_2015.pdf}

fileadmin
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: amazing idea, I like it and in my case where I use `LY1` encoding regularly, it works as well!