# How to do a -- sign in latex?

Tags: formatting, ascii

I'd like to print out two minus signs just after each other, like this -- (as in the C operator to subtract one). Doing `--` gives one longer - sign. I've tried `\char"2D\char"2D` but that also just gives one longer - sign. How can this be done?

Comment: You can try `-{}-`, but maybe provide some more information about the context (math mode, verbatim, ...?)

Comment: `-` in text is a hyphen not a minus sign. In math, `$--$` does not ligature to a dash

Comment: “as in the C operator” sounds like you try to add some kind of source code. In this case you should consider to add the source code verbatim or using a package like `listings` or `minted`, so `--` wouldn't be a ligature any longer. BTW: Adding a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) would help us to understand the question better and so to help you better.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Yes, I am writing C-code. I use ```\lstdefinestyle``` for larger blocks of code, but I've just changed the font when writing shorter snippets of code that resides within blocks of regular text. However, ```-{}-``` did the trick for now.

Comment: There are certain monospaced fonts, such as Fira Code or Jetbrains Mono that come with special ligatures, for example for `!=`, `->` and the like. `--` might be part of such a set of ligatures. In this case `-{}-` would be a temporal workaround. A better way would probably be to disable the ligature in question. However, it depends on the font whether or not this is possible and, if yes, how to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent LaTeX from creating en-dash and em-dash?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36692/how-do-i-prevent-latex-from-creating-en-dash-and-em-dash)

Answer (score 9):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$--$
-{}-
\verb|--|
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note: `-{}-` does not work with LuaLaTeX. There you would have to use something like `-\kern0pt-` or `-\/-` instead.

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed!

Comment: Why not `{-}{-}`?

Comment: @cabohah -- That seems an odd decision, to exclude `-{}-`.

Comment: @baldanders777, if that‘s what you were looking for, please accept the answer to raise Clara‘s reputation ;-)

Answer (score 1):

So I agree with the [@Clara's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681161) but I want to explain the reasons or the workings a bit.

As you already may have noticed, `-` produces a single minus. This is the same minus which would be used in hyphenations.

Adding a second minus `--` is the latex shortcut for an en-dash and `---` produces an em-dash. Both of these are used to typeset interjected sentences -- like this one -- or abrupt stops.

In order to generate two separate minuses
-- as in the above answer -- the command `-{}-` should be used. Here an empty scope is opened in between the two minuses. This stops LaTeX from joining them into an en-dash. The scope evaluates to nothing so there is no actual space added in between the minuses. The result is just two hyphenation-style minuses.

Comment: The [above answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681161) by @Clara (since the position on the page can change). \\ In your actual answer (as opposed to your TeX code) you probably want your `--` to be a Unicode ‘–’, but maybe the norm here on TeXSE is to use TeX formatting codes even when they aren't rendered. Anyway, grammatically I think you actually want an em dash ‘—’ or ‘---’ where you are using `--` in text. (It's not exactly covered by the Wiki article, but [self-interruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Self-interruption) may come close.) \\ There is a typo ‘hyphnation’.

Comment: I updated my answer. However depending on where you live and what kind of aesthetic preferences you have, you may use either an en-dash or an em-dash. In Germany for example em-dashes are basically never used (but en-dashes with spaces around) whereas in the US it is common to use em-dashes (without spaces around) instead of en-dashes.

Comment: Maybe to avoid confusion between hyphen and minus: `-` in text mode will actually print a glyph called "hyphen-minus" in Unicode. It is the glyph that is used in hyphenation, so, I typically prefer to call it a hyphen. There exists also a minus sign in some fonts which is a bit wider (as wide as a plus sign). In TeX, the equivalent to a minus is what would be typeset with `$-$`.