# Disable ligatures when using mk4ht to create html

Tags: pdftex, html, ligatures

How can I easily disable all ligatures, when converting my LaTex-file to html?

For the html-generation I am using the command-line

```
mk4ht htlatex file.tex 'xhtml,charset=utf-8' ' -cunihtf -utf8 -cvalidate' '-d./html/'
```

My latex document begins with the following lines

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{microtype}
```

As suggested in [How can I completely suppress ligatures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1841/how-can-i-completely-suppress-ligatures/34276) I tried the following options for microtype: `\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = *, family = * }`

The html-output though still contains characters **ﬁ**.

Comment: I don't think that `hyphenat` and `microtype` make much sense for `htlatex`.

Comment: @egreg You are right for `htlatex` but the document is intented for compilation using `pdflatex`. I only need to create an html once my document is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying several different options led to the following simple solution:

```
htlatex file.tex
```

I did not modify my preamble (stated in the question) and did not enable the command `\DisableLigatures`.

Comment: This does not work for me. Just running `htlatex` produces file which contains ligature characters instead of separated letters; ligatures are not acceptable for my use case.