# Proper use of cmap and mmap

Tags: pdftex, font-encodings, comparison

I am curious about the differences between

- `\usepackage{cmap}`
- `\usepackage[resetfonts]{cmap}`
- `\usepackage{mmap}` (= `\usepackage[useTeX]{mmap}`)
- `\usepackage[noTeX]{mmap}`

What are their precise differences? (I am not familiar with (La)TeX internals, so a beginner's explanation would be very helpful.) If this matters: I am using `\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}` (with `T3` being necessitated by the `tipa`-package), which is important in my case (but might not be important for a fully general answer to this question).

((Also, I am assuming that each of these commands would need to be loaded *after* loading package `fixltx2e` but *before* loading packages `times` and `fontenc`. Is that right?))

**Update:** [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64457/16550) starter code is great. I have uncommented the tipa-lines, saved the file in UTF-8 (and modified the input encoding line to `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, and went through all different cmap/mmap-options. However, I see no difference in the text that is pasted from the output pdf-file (perhaps because the MWE uses virtual fonts (by default?)?). Ideally, perhaps someone could help (both of us have tried a lot) to find a minimal example that shows five different output pasting behaviors when the only difference is whether no cmap/mmap or one of the 4 cmap/mmap options is loaded. Ideally that example would also specify the encoding the file is saved in to make this work (remember to not use a BOM for UTF-8; more importantly I don't know whether all input encodings lead to identical behavior (assuming correct escaping of accented characters in input encodings that don't offer a particular character)).

Comment: I am sadly not sure - I have a *very* large working file, and a few ligatures don't paste correctly. The thing is that I don't even know what a good working example would be that would illustrate the differences between these four commands (and my large working file might be mostly irrelevant to this question).
Basically I would like to use `cmap` for proper copy-and-paste abilities, but I've found information online about these other commands, and I'd like to know which one does what.

Answer (score 21):

The package `mmap` does a little bit more than `cmap`, it also works for mathematical symbols in your pdf.

So if your pdf does not use mathematics use `\usepackage{cmap}`.  If you have problems with ligatures further on with computer modern use `\usepackage[resetfonts]{cmap}`.
With mathemtic symbols use `\usepackage{mmap}`. If you have still problems use `\usepackage[noTeX]{mmap}`.

The differences are:

- `\usepackage{cmap}`: accepted preloaded fonts without reloading.
- `\usepackage[resetfonts]{cmap}`: as you can read in the README of cmap
  this forces the reloading of preloaded fonts (Computer Modern).
- `\usepackage[useTeX]{mmap}` and `\usepackage{mmap}`: does everything cmap
  does plus correcting mathematical symbols in your pdf; uses new
  -m.cmap files ("uses ascii strings for the macro-names").
- `\usepackage[noTeX]{mmap}`: does everything cmap does plus correcting
  mathematical symbols in your pdf; uses the cmap files (unicode).

Load `cmap` or `mmap` first, then `fontenc` and `babel`.

The documentation of `fixltx2e` does only say "load in the preamble". I had no problems loading it after `fontenc`, `babel` and the used fonts.

To do your own experiments use the follwing MWE:

```
\listfiles                      % shows used files
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
%\usepackage{cmap}              % pure T1 fonts 
%\usepackage[resetfonts]{cmap}  % pure T1 fonts, reset CM
%\usepackage{mmap}              % cmap + mathematics (ASCII)
%\usepackage[noTeX]{mmap}       % cmap + mathematics (Unicode)

 \usepackage[Latin9]{inputenc}  % or utf-8
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % font encription 
%\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}    % T3 for package tipa
%\usepackage{tipa}              % Phonetic alphabet
 \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}    % neue deutsche Rechtschreibung

%\usepackage{lmodern}           % Latin Modern
%\usepackage{tgpagella}         % has no virtual fonts
%\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}     % Minuskelziffern okay

%\usepackage{libertine}         % Libertine Legacy (with virtual fonts)
 \usepackage[osf]{libertine}    % mit Medivalziffern bzw. Minuskelziffern

\newcommand*{\III}{\libertineGlyph{Threeroman}}
\newcommand*{\IV}{\libertineGlyph{Fourroman}}


\begin{document}

Römische Zahlen: \III, \IV.

\textsc{Ligaturen}: auffliegen auffinden finden Auflage Schifffahrt.

\textsc{Korrekt}: auf\/fliegen auf\/finden finden Auf\/lage Schiff\/fahrt.

Ziffern: 0123456789.

Donau Donaudampfschiff Donaudampfschifffahrt Donaudampfschifffahrtskapitän 
Donaudampfschifffahrtskapitän 
Donaudampfschifffahrtskapitän Donaudampfschifffahrtskapitän 
Donaudampfschifffahrtskapitän Donaudampfschifffahrtskapitän

%\textipa{[\!b] [\:r] [\;B]}

\end{document}
```

Set or delete the comment sign to test `cmap` and `mmap` with or without `fontenc` and different fonts.

BTW: "Donaudampfschifffahrtskapitän" is a German word, good to get hyphenations.

Comment: Thank you. I am wondering what the practical difference between the two `mmap` commands is and what the practical difference between the two `cmap` commands is: What would be some code that gives to what precise differences in copy-and-paste behavior for each of these cases?

Comment: Thanks for your advice; it turns out that the actual problem I'm having is a very different, described [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64585/incompatibilities-of-cmap-with-fontenc-hyperref). That said, I lack the knowledge to really know how to build an MWE for *this* question, sorry about that. I'm just trying to use the right package commands.

Comment: No problem - I've created other, concise questions for my other issues. Still I think it'll be good for someone (could be someone else) to help find minimal contrasting examples illustrating the differences in output behavior between these four commands -- because I have tried and wasn't successful.

Comment: Thanks, this is great info! Could you edit your answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64188/what-are-good-ways-to-make-pdflatex-output-copy-and-pasteable) to include what you just wrote there? I think that would be a good place for this knowledge. Aside from that, it'll still be great if somebody else can help figure out differences for the four commands mentioned in *this* question.

Comment: For a recent ligature solution see  https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/new-package-selnolig-that-automates-suppression-of-typographic-ligature