# Accessibility issues

Tags: pdftex, accessibility

Currently, I'm generating the following pdf with pdflatex: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2682197/book.pdf

Unfortunately, this document is a bit incompatible with adobe screen reader (for blind people).

This audio recording demonstrates the result of using adobe screen reader with that document: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2682197/speech.mp3

In the recording, it's impossible to hear the chapter or section headers.

Any ideas of how to build a "more accessible" document?

Comment: What is the code that produces the output PDF?

Comment: I've done a lot of experiments with screenreaders on a lot of different documents; so far we have concluded that `pdf` documents are *not* screen-reader-accessible. We have found, particularly for documents that have mathematical content, the best way (***by far*** is to use `htlatex myfile.tex "html,mathml"` and then have the screen reader act on the `(x)html` file. `MathML` was designed with accessibility in mind. If you'd like me to convert this into an answer, let me know

Comment: This is not surprising at all, given that PDF doesn't really care about the meaning of its content, while HTML is a markup language, (theorically, when properly used) emphasizing the meaning of its content over the aspect (which should be dealt with using CSS).

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys. You convinced me that there's not a good way to make my pdf document more accessible.  @cmhughes, you may convert your comment to a answer if you want.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128454/are-there-any-open-problems-in-the-world-of-tex. Maybe people will see this as an interesting project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your PDF doesn't has the right Character Map defined. You can see that when you copy an heading:

> CucZ Z u«±§¶±¶§Z o £§u±

You have the same problem many people have, that you can't copy or search the text in the pdf. There are basically two different things you can use: `cmap` or `\pdfgentounicode`.
How and when you should use which, is explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72904/5042) by Heiko. I have found that it resolves all issues I had with copying and now I can even copy most math.

There is also the package `mmap`, which you can use instead of `cmap`. More is explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64457/5042)

Comment: It worked! I used the `\pdfgentounicode` solution and it solved the chapter/section headers reading! Thanks!

Comment: I'm still having problems with the reading of excerpts of programming languages code in the document generated... Any ideas of how to make them more "readable"? Some punctuation chars from the code (such as "object.method();" from a java code) are ignored by the reader... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 10):

I'm working on a committee to address accessibility at [my institution](http://www.pcc.edu/), and we have done a lot of experiments with screen readers on a lot of different documents.

So far we have concluded that `pdf` documents, no matter how they were generated (`LaTeX`, `Word`, `LibreOffice`, etc), are not screen-reader-accessible when they contain mathematical content.

We have found, particularly for documents that have mathematical content, the best way *by far* is to convert the `.tex` file into an `html` file that has `MathML` content using, for example,

```
htlatex myfile.tex "html,mathml"
```

and then have the screen reader act on the `(x)html` file. Interestingly, we have found that while Firefox can render `MathML` easily, the screen reader (we use [Jaws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAWS_%28screen_reader%29)) works better with Internet Explorer with [Mathplayer](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathplayer/).

[MathML greatly improves accessibility](http://www.w3.org/Math/) of mathematical documents. Indeed, from this format one can either go down the screen reader or the Nemeth Braille route. Some questions that you might also like to have a look at:

- [LaTeX to Braille](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32609/latex-to-braille)
- [Is there an easy way to add hover text to all incidents of math mode where the hover text would contain the LaTeX code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32314/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-hover-text-to-all-incidents-of-math-mode-where-the-h)

Answer (score 7):

One problem with doing a good conversion to a readable document can also be that you haven't got the reading order in the PDF right. This is related to the internal structure of the PDF. There are no widely-recognized or default solutions for this, but you might be interested to try the [`accessibility` package](http://www.babs.gmxhome.de/download/da_pdftex/accessibility.sty).

If you can't read the German documentation at http://www.babs.gmxhome.de/download/da_pdftex/dok_pdf.pdf, the short version is that you need to include this line in your preamble:

```
    \usepackage[tagged]{accessibility}
```

which is enough to generate a `tagged` pdf which then has the correct reading order. Because this is a package that is useful for other [accessibility](/questions/tagged/accessibility) solutions, it would be interesting to hear more about your experiences.

Comment: I realize that this is not the issue with this specific case, but it may be a solution to other problems with the same symptoms.

Comment: There appears to be an updated [accessibility-meta](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194226/107497).

Comment: Anyone stumbling on this should note that at the moment the `accessibility` package is badly broken (I'm the maintainer; currently it looks more like we'll have to start again from scratch)... Feel free to post issues to https://github.com/AndyClifton/accessibility/issues.

Answer (score 0):

I found my way to this question with a similar issue: I was attempting to use LaTeX to create a mathematics-bearing PDF document that could be parsed by a screen reader. I tried some of the solutions suggested here (`cmap`, `\pdfgentounicode`) to no avail.

What did eventually work for me was changing the font to Times New Roman with `\usepackage{times}`. It certainly made my document look worse, and it broke a few other visual elements, but it completely repaired the halting cadence of the screen reader on my document as well as fixing the screen reader's difficulty with joined ligatures (e.g. "fi" not being rendered as two separate letters). This also let me continue my normal PDF rendering work flow without any other major adjustments.

I'll note that the screen reader still performed awkwardly on mathematical expressions, but that strikes me as likely unavoidable, and I was happy to at least have the screen reader perform well on the text portions of the document.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.