# How to use the new pdfTeX feature "\pdfinterwordspaceon"

Tags: pdftex, texlive

According to the [docu](http://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-820009.2) there are some new features in texlive 2014. One of them is a command `\pdfinterwordspaceon`. It seems as if it adds spaces between the words, so that I can just copy and paste from a PDF. OK.

Can somebody give an example where this command is useful? Years ago I had issues with text copied from PDF without any space between words, but that was long ago. Even under texlive 2013 I can open a PDF and copy the text including the spaces between words.

Comment: AFAIK it's needed for PDF/A.

Answer (score 1):

This is needed for PDF/A compatibility, but also for accessibility. Accessible PDFs are supposed to be able to read out aloud by a screen reader software.

Comment: Can you give an example where the usage of `\pdfinterwordspaceon` makes a difference? Because I checked with lmodern as well as with Linux Libertine as fonts and there was no gain.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot provide a minimal example. However the difference becomes noticable, if you want to create a tagged PDF, i.e. with babette schalitz "accessibility.sty" or related http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-2/tb95moore.pdf - When extracting the structual content and surrounding them with tags, there will be no spaces. See also here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124291/revisiting-producing-structured-pdfs-from-latex - Maybe it's already visible, if you open Acrobat Pro and try to see the tag structure there...

Comment: @KeksDose An MWE is in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/317586/30810