# How can I create a tagged PDF/UA document with pdfx?

Tags: accessibility, pdfx

I know this question has been asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579/how-can-tagged-pdfs-be-created-that-support-universal-accessibility-and-reflowin), but it was last active 4 years ago and I'm hoping the situation has improved since then. I've been looking at using the pdfx package with the ua option, with the intention of making the document accessible for screen readers, etc.

I can add \usepackage[ua]{pdfx} to my document without issue, but I don't know how to actually create the necessary tags. I found [this page](http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~ross/TaggedPDF/) with plenty of examples, but it only has the PDF files, and not the LaTeX/xmpdata sources. I've also read the pdfx manual, but it's unhelpful.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: A more up to date question is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124291/107497.  The higher voted answer (last comment) points you to https://github.com/AndyClifton/strucPDF, and you can do `\usepackage[tagged]{strucPDF}` and cross your fingers.

Comment: the pdfx package has no code to tag a pdf and the code  used on the page you linked to is imho not public. But  you could try the (experimental) tagpdf package, it is on ctan.

Comment: Thanks, I tried tagpdf and some of AndyClifton's packages (strucPDF seems to be gone, but he has a few others), but none seem to do the trick, alas.

Comment: You should use @UlrikeFischer if you want to notify people in a comment. If you want help with the tagpdf package you will have to show (here or in the issue tracker of the package) a small example which demonstrates what you tried and what didn't work.