# A guide on how to produce accessible PDF files?

Tags: pdftex, accessibility, pdf-a, tagged-pdf

**First:** I know that this has been asked before:

- [How can tagged PDFs be created that support Universal Accessibility and reflowing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579/how-can-tagged-pdfs-be-created-that-support-universal-accessibility-and-reflowin) (06/2010)
- [LaTeX accessibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19279/latex-accessibility) (05/2011)
- [Accessibility issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76027/accessibility-issues?rq=1) (10/2012)
- [Revisiting producing structured PDFs from LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124291/revisiting-producing-structured-pdfs-from-latex) (06/2013)

There has been a couple of questions closed about accessibility and LaTeX since these questions.

I am also aware of [Ross More's paper](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-2/tb95moore.pdf) from 2009 and [his presentation from 2010](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/tex-mathml-for-tagged-pdf-the-next-frontier-in-mathematical-typesetting/).

---

**The question is still:** *Is possible to make PDF files that are accessible using LaTeX?*

I understand that one can disagree on what *accessible* means. Different countries/regions will have different (legal) definitions. I am interested in how accessibility is understood in different countries, but for this question my main concern is the US context. Here I believe that Americans with Disabilities Act of 1990 (ADA)/Section 508 is what defines what accessible content is. More concretely, I am thinking being able to read the PDF file using a screen reader (like JAWS). Concretely the desire is to create pdf files that can be used in a class setting at a university where federal law requires that content is accessible. This is a real concern ([see for example this](https://nfb.org/images/nfb/documents/pdf/miami%20teach.pdf)).

The standard way to check whether a pdf file is accessible seems to to use Adobe Pro's accessibility checker. This can, for example, reveal whether a document is tagged. But it also seems like one needs to actually test it with a screen reader to make sure that everything is as desired.

Right now using pdfLaTeX and checking with Adobe Pro's accessibility checker I in general get two errors:

- the page lacks a language specification and
- there are no tags.

I am hoping that there has been some development over the last two years on this. Even though I use LaTeX frequently, I still consider myself a casual user. Answers in the past seem to point out that there are ways to do this, but I haven't been able to find a user friendly guide written in English. I have checked some document where text is read by a screen reader, but the problem seems to be the mathematics content.

From what I can understand it isn't possible to create a truly accessible PDF file. If this is true, I am wondering:

**Question**: What is the current best practice is to create accessible PDF files? Are there are user friendly guides available?

I am also aware of this answer (from 08/2014):

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194226/5870

Here it is pointed out in the comments that the created PDF file doesn't pass the accessibility checker in Adobe Pro. Also, one actually has to edit the `.sty` file that is used. (I still think it is a great answer!) Also, this file might have been created for a German context (but might still have international use?)

Comment: There is all [accsupp](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/accsupp). One issue I see is that stuff has been created without clear licensing or distributed in a way which undermines further unclear licensing, and never even makes it to CTAN let alone into TeX distros. A lot of work is being wasted and, in the meantime, Word documents remain the gold standard in terms of accessibility. (That's what we're advised to provide, although I don't. But if I have a student who needs it, I'll have to.)

Comment: I typically take a different approach: create (or convert to) structured content; this allows you to create a tex file with associated beautiful PDF, together with screen-reader accessible HTML/ePUB. Possible conversion tools from tex to XML include plastex

Comment: ross moore presented a [further paper](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/semantic-enrichment-of-mathematics-using-%E2%80%98active-comments%E2%80%99/) on this topic at tug 2015.  also, olaf  drümmer talked about the [standardization of pdf/ua](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/pdfua%E2%80%94what-it-is-how-users-can-benefit-from-it-and-how-to-get-it-right/).  both talks are now on line.  there is still manual adjustment needed to provide all necessary metadata.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thank you for the links to the updated material. It sounds like the answer is simply that accessible PDF files are nearly impossible to make with LaTeX. (I still don't understand that legal standard though.)

Comment: See [ac­cess PDF fea­tures](http://ctan.org/topic/pdf-feat) topic on CTAN. May be too obvious, but probably the best  solution at least for a highly formated PDF is attach a plain text version that can be easily reproduced by some text-to-speech system as `festival`  or even a script for lauch this program easily.

Comment: Language is an easy fix with ```\usepackage[pdflang={en-US},pdftex]{hyperref}``` but the tags are harder.

Comment: To add tags to your document you can use \hypersetup{pdftitle=your title,
pdfauthor={your name},
pdfkeywords={tag1, tag2, tag3},
} to your preamble.  I am not sure, whether this is the thing you're searching for.

Comment: @Carina Keyword tags are something else.  Tags in a pdf allows a screen reader to figure out what is going on with the pdf that it's reading.

Comment: The [axessibility package](https://ctan.org/pkg/axessibility) is now available, which adds hidden LaTeX code comments to pdf files. They say it works with certain screen readers.

Comment: Perhaps another alternative is to generate and use HTML, or link to an accessible HTML version of the TeX output? I can add this as an answer if it would be helpful, but I've not looked into this too deeply.

Comment: It seems there has been some hopeful developments on this issue: https://www.latex-project.org/news/2020/11/30/tagged-pdf-FS-study/

Comment: Here are some other questions related to accessibility of maths: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454944/is-there-screen-reader-software-or-a-built-in-method-that-supports-latex-equat , https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352649/can-we-get-maths-in-pdfs-that-can-be-copy-pasted-and-screen-read , and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233390/in-which-way-have-fake-spaces-made-it-to-actual-use

Comment: @cmhughes:  If your comment is still valid (in August 2021), then could you please provide an example with detials?  I would appreciate it.

Comment: @sony I believe its still relevant :) I use make4ht for conversion. Do you have a specific xml schema that you're aiming for?

Comment: @cmhughes  At the moment I have no ideas.  I was wondering what you meant by saying "create (or convert to) structured content; this allows you to create a tex file with associated beautiful PDF, together with screen-reader accessible HTML/ePUB." :)

Comment: @sony the PreTexT project is an example of something that starts in Xml (structured content) . From there, multiple different outputs are facilitated. Full details at https://pretextbook.org/. Here's a link to a sample pretext project : https://spaces.pcc.edu/display/MS/ORCCA if you have the option and the freedom to choose, I would advocate exploring this project

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas where would I look for information on this topic more recent than 2021 ... ?????

Answer (score 19):

Accessibility requires a number of settings in the PDF. Some of them are rather easy to implement (e.g. that a title and the language should be set) other are more difficult. The most difficult part is the requirement that the PDF should be "tagged", this means that it contains structure informations.

The LaTeX Team has started a multi-year project "Tagged PDF" to allow LaTeX to create such tagged PDF. Details of the project can be found at
https://www.latex-project.org/news/2020/11/30/tagged-pdf-FS-study/

The current state of the project is that paragraphs and links can be tagged automatically. This requires a current LaTeX, a current `pdfmanagement-testphase` and the current version of the experimental research package `tagpdf` (and currently still lualatex):

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{uncompress,pdfversion=2.0}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{activate,paratagging,interwordspace}
\usepackage{hyperref,lipsum}
\begin{document}

Tagged project: \url{https://www.latex-project.org/news/2020/11/30/tagged-pdf-FS-study/}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

The structure of the PDF (compile twice) can be inspected at https://ngpdf.com.

Other structure elements can be tagged too, but this has to be done manually (or by patching commands). The next task will be to add automatic tagging to basic structures like sections and lists.

The coming TUG conference will have a few talks about the progress of the project  https://www.tug.org/tug2021/index.html

#### Update April 2023

with the latest latex-dev release more tagging related test code has been released https://www.latex-project.org/news/2023/03/13/latex-dev-1/. So now
this here can be tagged

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-III,testphase=math}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 
\section{section}
\subsection{Subsection}%

some text with a \footnote{a footnote}

\begin{enumerate}
\item a list
 \begin{itemize}
  \item more list
 \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{verbatim}
some verbatim
some verbatim
\end{verbatim}

inline math $a=b$

display math
\begin{equation}
x=y
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The tagging of graphics is under development (there is already branch in the github), and floats are handled soon too. With the june release it should be possible to tag most standard commands.

### Update February 2024

With the newest LaTeX release in june and november 2023 support for graphics, floats and support for basic tables has been added. The newest LaTeX-dev in february 2024 corrected various issues and added support for marginpar (that is loaded automatically in phase-III), for `\maketitle` (this must currently be loaded explicitly as `title` module). The `math` module has been reworked and extended and now contains code to attach semi-automatically mathml representations of equations. It now also handles the amsmath `\text` command (but some other commands which internally use `\mathchoice` are still open and can led to faulty structures). Some examples that has been tagged with the new code are at https://github.com/latex3/tagging-project/discussions/56.

In summary that means that (with the exception of the `tabbing` environment) almost everything described in the Leslie Lamport manual can now be tagged.

Documentations about the various modules can be found with `texdoc -l latex-lab`. They describe options but also restrictions and open problems.

We created a special repository for issues, discussions and feedback: https://github.com/latex3/tagging-project

Comment: This is great news. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Any updates on this topic?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I added an update.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 14):

It seems the answer was hiding in a footnote of [this paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jbigham/pubs/pdfs/2015/accessibleconferences.pdf) on making ADA compliant PDFs. [See this project!](https://code.google.com/p/sigchi-latex/wiki/Accessibility)

UPDATE: Having spent time attempting to use this tool in conjunction with a complex custom class, I want to temper expectations. While the accessibility.sty package is a useful tool for simple documents, it is incompatible with multiple packages and commands. An improved version of the package, called [accessibility_meta](https://github.com/NREL/latex_editing/blob/master/article/accessibilityMeta.sty), is available [here](https://github.com/NREL/latex_editing/blob/master/article/accessibilityMeta.sty).

Even the updated package is not perfect. For example neither work with the package "fancyhdr" nor with simple commands like "\setlist".

UPDATE 2: The `accessibility.sty` package is [now on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/accessibility), but [still has issues](https://github.com/AndyClifton/accessibility/issues).

Comment: I'm the maintainer of `accessibility` and had taken it over to get it on to CTAN. For the reasons you identified in your other answer (it breaks every time another package or LaTeX changes) I am going to withdraw it from CTAN. I can no longer recommend using it!

Comment: This accessibility package never really worked. It is obsolete as of today. Consider deleting the answer.

Answer (score 10):

This answer presents what seems to me the most efficient way to improve the accessibility of LaTeX documents. Unfortunately, it requires the use of R and Adobe Acrobat. My previous approach involved using only a modified version of Babett Schaltz’s accessibility.sty. (Schaltz created it as part of her 2007 PhD thesis in Germany.) Despite making hundreds of modifications to the original .sty file, the arrival of new incompatibilities with every MikTeX update led me to switch to my current approach.

The first step involves *knitting* an RMarkdown file, however adding the following commands to the header of your standard LaTeX document will allow you to follow along from step two.

```
\RequirePackage{accsupp}
\RequirePackage{pdfcomment}
\newcommand{\AccTool}[2]{\BeginAccSupp{method=pdfstringdef,unicode,Alt={{#1}}}\pdftooltip{{#2}}{{#1}}\EndAccSupp{}}
```

## Step 1: Generate TeX Output Using RMarkdown

[Click this text to access the example Rmd file](http://www.richschwinn.com/accessibility/accessibility_example.Rmd), or download all of the content by clicking [here](http://www.richschwinn.com/accessibility/accessibility_archive.zip). The first difference between this file and a plain Rmd is the YAML. The **fontsize** command does what you might expect. The **keep_tex** command ensures we have access to the intermediate files for step two. Finally, the **header_includes** command adds required LaTeX code to the header.

```
fontsize: 11pt
output:
  pdf_document:   
    keep_tex: yes
header-includes:
   - \RequirePackage{accsupp}
   - \RequirePackage{pdfcomment}
   - \newcommand{\AccTool}[2]{\BeginAccSupp{method=pdfstringdef,unicode,Alt={{#1}}}\pdftooltip{{#2}}{{#1}}\EndAccSupp{}}
```

## Step 2: Make Modifications to the TeX

[This file](http://www.richschwinn.com/accessibility/accessibility_post_processing.R) will modify the TeX output from step one. It uses R's **gsub** command to add tooltips and accessibility tags to the document. One can design clever regular expressions to capture caption text for the accessibility tags. To learn regular expressions [visit this website](http://www.regexone.com). I used a ~100-line variation of this file to add more than 1,000 tags to this [218-page document](https://go.usa.gov/xQT4w).

The last line of the script uses the **texi2pdf** command to generate a PDF file.

## Step 3: Run Adobe Acrobat Scripts

The final step requires Adobe Acrobat Pro. Open the PDF file generated in step two and perform the accessibilty actions defined in [this Acrobat script](http://www.richschwinn.com/accessibility/accessibility.sequ). You can install the scripts by simply opening the [accessibility.sequ](http://www.richschwinn.com/accessibility/accessibility.sequ) file if Acrobat is installed. You can access the script under **Tools**-->**Action Wizard**. For those managing multiple documents, Acrobat offers simple batch processing which you can apply to the [accessibility.sequ](http://www.richschwinn.com/accessibility/accessibility.sequ) commands.

## Results

After performing all three steps, your document will be far closer to 508 compliance than the original *knitr* ouput. Among the four issues remaining after processing, **logical reading order** and **color contrast** always require manual judgement, **Title** is fixed with two clicks, and the final **Headings-Nesting** rule can be skipped [according to Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/create-verify-pdf-accessibility.html?trackingid=KACNN#Headings). Specifically they say, "The order of headings is not required under WCAG, and is only an advisory technique."

[image: accessibility checks]

Notice the figure's alternative text tooltip:
[image]

Comment: Back to the R requirement, it seems that the first two steps are really just to get the appropriate TeX code in place.  Is that correct?  Could someone hardcode their TeX file so that step 3 would work?

Comment: Absolutely correct.