# Adding accessibility package causes error: 'Use of \reserved@a doesn't match its definition'

Tags: accessibility

I am making an attempt at making my thesis more accessible. Based on the advice on this page, [Creating Accessible Documents](https://libguides.lib.msu.edu/c.php?g=995742&p=8207771), I'm trying to include the following package to start with:

`\usepackage[tagged, highstructure]{accessibility}`

However, just including this package gives me the following error. I'm a LaTeX novice so I'm having trouble making sense of it or tracing where it comes from. I'm using Overleaf.

```
Use of \reserved@a doesn't match its definition.

\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.163 \tableofcontents

If you say, e.g., '\def\a1{...}', then you must
always put '1' after '\a', since control sequence
names are made up of letters only. The macro here
has not been followed by the required stuff, so
I'm ignoring it.
```

This appears to be the definition of `\tableofcontents` in the `ucthesis.cls` document class I'm using:

```
\def\tableofcontents{\@restonecolfalse
  \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn\fi
  \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{\uppercase{\contentsname}}{\uppercase{\contentsname}}}%
  {\ssp\@starttoc{toc} \addtocontents{toc}{\hbox to \linewidth{\hfill Page}}}\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi}
```

But I'm having trouble figuring out where `\reserved@a` is being defined or where it is being used incorrectly, and though I have a vague idea of the use of `@` symbols in command names as a way of locking the names down, I can't tell if the error message example of `\def\a1{...}` is relevant since there are no numbers in the name.

Comment: The accessibility package doesn't work. Even if you manage to avoid the errors it will not produce a correct tagged pdf.  See also the comment here https://ctan.org/pkg/accessibility.  Regarding the  general status of accessibility see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/605142/2388

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. I'll close this as a duplicate.