# Adding a Title and Tags to a PDF Generated with LaTeX for Better Accessibility

Tags: accessibility

After each day of class, I upload a PDF of my class notes to my college's learning management system (LMS) so that my students can have access to them. The LMS checks for accessibility issues with all PDF documents uploaded. Every time I upload a PDF generated in LaTeX, it yells at me because

1. "The document is missing a title"
2. "The PDF is untagged"

I know that it is relatively straightforward to fix these issues in Adobe Acrobat (and other similar software), but I would need to do this fix every single time I update a file. **Is there a way that I can programmatically add a title and tags to PDFs generated with LaTeX?**

Note that my documents do always begin with a title created via `\title` in the preamble, and `\maketitle` at the start of the document.

Comment: Tagging and accessibility is an ongoing project by the LaTeX3 development team. A lot of basic tagging now works. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/261537/2693.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some things, you can do like:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\hypersetup{
pdftitle={Title of your paper},
pdfauthor={Author Names},
pdfkeywords={Important Keywords},%
}
```

For like `Accessibility and Tagged PDF`, already @Alan; said in his comment.

Also, please refer the recent post from `Ulrike` [A guide on how to produce accessible PDF files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261537/a-guide-on-how-to-produce-accessible-pdf-files)

Comment: you need also the option `pdfdisplaydoctitle` (accessibility requires that the window title show the title and not the file name).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I always requested you to modify the suggestion, as I'm not good in English, thanks