# Problem using mmap, mathpazo and siunitx

Tags: errors, siunitx, font-encodings, mathpazo

I have these packages in my preamble: `siunitx`, `mmap`, `mathpazo` that somehow seem to mess things up. A minimum working example that shows the error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mmap}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathpazo}    % fancy math fonts

\begin{document}

Hello world.

\end{document}
```

The error I get (using MikTeX 2.9 and LuaLaTeX or pdftex) is

```
...
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\siunitx\config\siunitx-binary.cfg
")
! Argument of strip@CM@prefix@ has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
            par 
l.9 \begin{document}
```

If it helps, I've observed that the order of the packages makes no difference. I get the same error. Googling the issue gave no results.

Is there a workaround for this?

#### Edit by diabonas:

The problem doesn't seem to be related to `siunitx`, apparently `mmap` doesn't support math fonts other than the default Computer Modern: Even a simple

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mmap}
\usepackage{mathpazo}    % fancy math fonts
\begin{document}
$Hello$
\end{document}
```

produces the `\strip@CM@prefix@`-error.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @dcherian I've simplified the minimal (non)working example further - see my edit. Apparently the problem isn't related to `siunitx`, the problem seems to be that `mmap` doesn't support math fonts other than the default Computer Modern :-(

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce that. What do I do with the question now?

Comment: @dcherian I'd try reformulating it to "Is it possible to use `mmap` with math fonts other than Computer Modern?", in the hope that one of the PDF/font experts here is able to help. I'm afraid though that the answer is "no, it isn't, use `glyphtounicode` instead" as you already suggested - however I'm not competent enough to judge this, so maybe there actually is a way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer originally part of the question

I've done some more checking around. Replacing `mmap` with `\input{glyphtounicode.tex}` works. Further, this comment ( [What are good ways to make pdflatex output copy-and-pasteable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64188/what-are-good-ways-to-make-pdflatex-output-copy-and-pasteable/64198#64198) ) says that mmap doesn't work with virtual fonts. The `mathpazo`  readme ( http://www.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/fonts/mathpazo/README ) says that it uses virtual fonts. Is this the problem?